# https-proxy-agent upgraded to 3.0.0 but npm audit still showing not fixed

Tags: angular, security, npm, audit, https-proxy-agent

As of October 18, 2019, with a fix provided for NPM package **https-proxy-agent**, even after upgrading to the latest version, the audit warning still shows as 6 high vulnerabilities.

Running **npm audit fix** doesn't resolve or remove the warnings, neither does **npm audit fix --force** (which is not encouraged).  The warning shows no matter.

It still shows the following affected dependencies:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                Manual Review                                 │
│            Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve            │
│                                                                              │
│         Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular/cli [dev]                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular/cli > @schematics/update > pacote >                 │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular/cli [dev]                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular/cli > pacote > make-fetch-happen >                  │
│               │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular/cli [dev]                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular/cli > @schematics/update > pacote >                 │
│               │ npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @angular/cli [dev]                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @angular/cli > pacote > npm-registry-fetch >                 │
│               │ make-fetch-happen > https-proxy-agent                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ protractor [dev]                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ protractor > browserstack > https-proxy-agent                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Machine-In-The-Middle                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ https-proxy-agent                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=3.0.0                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ protractor [dev]                                             │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ protractor > saucelabs > https-proxy-agent                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1184                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
found 6 high severity vulnerabilities in 17441 scanned packages
 6 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

What do I need to upgrade (**npm install some-package@latest --save**) to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here.

Found a matching open issue on the angular github:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15878

In this issue a temporary workaround is described by Josh Stabback:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-https-proxy-agent/issues/84#issuecomment-543884972

I followed the step-by-step instructions and got a clean audit result:

```
=== npm audit security report === 
found 0 vulnerabilities
in 18853 scanned packages
```

Thanks a lot @ Josh Stabback for documenting the workaround.

Comment: That worked, but I found all I needed to do was add to package.json

"resolutions": {
        "https-proxy-agent": "^3.0.0"
    }

and then run npm audit fix and it resolved the warnings regarding https-proxy-agent.